# CSS: modificar Estilo predeterminado

Tags: javascript, css, angular, web

Intento eliminar un box-shadow de una clase "predeterminada" llamada 'sketch-picker' y estoy fracasando en el intento. La clase viene por default con el componente color-sketch, le agregue 2 botones pero me quedan separadas por una linea que se elimina quitando la propiedad 'box-shadow'.
Estoy tratando de eliminarlo pero no lo estoy consiguiendo:

EDITADO: Mas especificamente, esta tomando la clase pero no aplica el 'box-shadow' por que interpreta que tiene mas "jerarquia" la clase 'sketch-picker'.

CSS:

```
::ng-deep {
    .box .sketch-picker{
        box-shadow: none;
    } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<color-sketch class="box"
  [color]="color"
  (onChange)="changeComplete($event)"
></color-sketch>
<div class="color-picker-buttons">
  <ion-button (click)="close()" color="medium" size="small"> {{ 'UTILS.SKIP' | translate }} </ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="save()" color="primary" size="small"> {{ 'UTILS.SAVE' | translate }} </ion-button>
</div>
```

CAPTURAS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resuelto: Se agrego !important despues de la propiedad en la clase css.
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUiiU.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con !important atras de none

Comment: Perfecto @HernánGarcia, era eso!
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado!
El css quedo asi:

```
::ng-deep {
    .box .sketch-picker{
        box-shadow: none !important;
    } 
}
```

La regla !important en CSS se utiliza para añadir más importancia a una propiedad/valor de lo normal.

De hecho, si utiliza la regla !important, anulará TODAS las reglas de estilo anteriores para esa propiedad específica en ese elemento.

De esta manera logre desactivar esa regla de estilo del componente en ese caso particular.